# PHP curl_multi_exec is using 99% cpu . Any special apache or php configuration to lower cpu usage?

Tags: php, apache, curl

By runing the basic example from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.curl-multi-exec.php) , httpd.exe is using 99% cpu . Are there any
php or apache configuration to fix this ? I know i don't have enough processing power
, but I have never seen such a simple script to load that much a 2,4GHz single core cpu .

P.S. : The script just hangs and nothing happens and laptop just freezes .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    curl_multi_select($mh);
} while ($running > 0);

?>
```

That code would fix the problem . The problem was because of CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM , which is deprecated on newer versions of libcurl (7.2 +) . This was causing a countinuous loop => 99% cpu load .